# Logic analyser or oscilloscope?

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, analog, oscilloscope, protocol

I am an embedded enthusiast and very much into embedded C and firmware development.  I love to interface different sensors and modules to MCU by creating my own libraries from scratch.

Now for understanding signals and protocols used by sensors and modules like UART, SPI(High-speed ones too), I2C, timers, PWM waves(of order ns, us, ms), one wire communication, ADC, CSI, RS232, IR receiver protocols, RF433 module of and many such protocols used in different MCU to interface different sensors and modules (like using STM32, NRF5.)

So which equipment I should go for,  a logic analyser or oscilloscope?

My personal thought is to go with a logic analyser, as my main task is with handling MCU protocols and almost all of them work on digital signals only, that is what logic analyser is mainly for I guess.

But I am confused as to which logic analyser will be best for my needs.

Still on the choice between logic analyser and oscilloscope, experts advice from you all?

P.S. I am loking for cheap solution, not too expensive.)

Comment: They are for completely different tasks. You can't see analog signal problems with a logic analyzer, or digital signal problems with a scope. Some scopes have logic analyzer, and some logic analyzers have analog sampling, so maybe one device can work for both. It depends whether you need to solve mostly analog problems (like I2C does not work because pullup is 47k instead of 4k7, or SPI does not work because IO pin is configured as output while it should be input) or digital problems (the timing or data or protocol on a bus is not right).

Comment: Both.  Get a cheap USB based logic analyzer to use with sigrok, then save your money for a conventional bench scope.

Comment: I have been using an US$300 50MHz, 4 channel storage scope (DS1054) for 5 years, mainly displaying my Micky Mouse Rpi projects' UART, SPI, I2C signals under 10MHz. I did once use expensive logic analyzers, but I don't feel like to have one, because I don't need one. Most of the time my US$10 DVM is more than enough to troubleshoot my stupid software bugs and hardware wiring..

Comment: get a scope, note ignore any built in protocol analyzers (spi, i2c, etc) they are often wrong, best to just use your eyes.  With a bidirectional bus like i2c you can see who is driving the data line on a scope cant see on an analyzer, harder to debug.  You can turn an mcu into a digital logger and use that as a logic analyzer once you know the other protocols and can program a/the mcu...

Answer (score 11):

Once you've got a bomb-proof digital system going, then a logic analyser is great if you want to see complex signals across wide busses, or time, or codes.

Until you've got said bomb-proof system going, an oscilloscope is essential for figuring out why your so-called digital system is behaving in an analogue way with ground bounce, logic overshoots, slow edges causing multiple clocks through oscillation.

A two, or preferably four channel scope can handle enough signals for de-fleaing I2C, serial and SPI communications. Even with wide busses, a clock, a strobe and a couple of MSBs are enough to sort out what's going on.

If you only have bench space or resources for one instrument, get a scope.

Comment: What do u mean by Bomb-Proof digital system?

Comment: [Bomb Proof](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bombproof). Robust, always works properly, behaves itself, not intermittent or flaky. Not suffering from effects like ground bounce, or overshoots, or slow edges which can make digital systems fail to work sometimes.

Comment: Most new Tek scopes can give up to 4 logic analyser channels per scope channel. The low end are not particularly expensive but more than many hobbyists might be prepared to pay.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your audio card as a scope with free software or USB DIY with HC05 type Logic analyzers that are cheap, but a good working knowledge of digital and analog Impedances with signal integrity requires a good DSO to learn and a cheap substitute to understand the short comings with more debug time wasted.  I preferred a 48 channel LA over a scope when the logic was intermittent.  But that was when most parallel busses were exposed. Now,  it’s easier with a serial world, so I would hunt for a protocol analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

Digilent sells a compact, inexpensive (in relative terms), "all in one lab" type device that has an oscilloscope, logic analyzer, power supply, and some other stuff.

[Analog Discovery Studio](https://store.digilentinc.com/analog-discovery-studio-a-portable-circuits-laboratory-for-every-student/)

I have an older version that was less expensive but they don't sell that anymore. This one looks much nicer anyway. You can't go to very high frequencies, but for the stuff you're talking about, it's probably a good option.

Answer (score 0):

A scope is sure a nice thing, but for my use cases(*), which sound quite similar to the author, I'd choose a logic analyzer any day. Several reasons

- Being able to capture, save and analyze multiple channels for a long(seconds or more) timeframe is much more important than being able to exactly see the waveform of a single clock cycle - or eight.
- Takes much less bench space and is much more portable and easy to use on the move.
- A perfectly fine LA costs significantly less than an entry-level scope. Even a cheap 8-channel one($6-$8 on ebay) paired with sigrok is surprisingly useful.

(*) In my experience, all issues in 'ordinary' digital/mixed-mode devices could be solved by a combination of a good multimeter, schematic review, a logic analyzer and common sense. If designing something high-speed, or high-precision, or low power, etc. then get an oscilloscope, and make sure it's good, not a low-cost USB one. But for measuring temperature, blinking LEDs and interfacing with different ICs, a scope is usually an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Why not both? Depending on your budget, a mixed signal oscilloscope should be your friend. I second what @Neil_UK wrote, that until you're sure your signal is correct an oscilloscope is greatly useful. As someone who mostly deals with software/firmware bringup and programming I found a two channel scope with a built-in sixteen channel (I rarely used more than four or five) logic analyzer great. Four channels would be more usuful but that's not a necessity. Also, if like me, you mainly deal with firmware do consider a PC scope.

Answer (score 0):

I also thought about both devics an I bought a https://www.dreamsourcelab.com/product/dslogic-series/ Logic analyser first (I can recomand this one). Compared to what posibilities it offers, a good LA is much cheaper than a good scope.

If you want to analyse e.g. a 25MHz SPI, e.g. the DSLogic is far remote its limits and you almost have the convinience of a 100.000€ LA from more than 20 years ago.
For a Osciloscope, with a 25MHz digital dignal, you already need at least a 200MHz analog Bandwidth scope and 1-2Ghz sampling Rate - just to see the signal shape almost exactly. And if you realy have a design Problem in your circuit board (I used to have exacly such a case some years ago) a 2GHz scope with an low capacity active probe just started to show the problem. And here we talk about some 30.000€ equipment already.
So I guess the selection and decision process for a osciloscope is much more time consuming. Go with the LA first.